# Has Magento CE built-in refine search features?

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. I need to show refine search on left side. Is there any built-in or 3rdparty Magento CE extension for refine search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an inbuilt refine search in magento. That is known as `layered navigation`. you need to just data to the store and you'll get default filters that is price and sub-categories. Rest to need to add through adding attributes.